# How to put another NSString if my NSLocalizable for example "en"

Tags: ios, json, nsstring, nslocalizedstring

I have question. I have url which parse some data from JSON. Also i have two JSON: One JSON is world news on english language and second for example the same news but on spain language. So i must check if my phone use english language system my application must use JSON ONE with english world news. So if i use spain language my app also must use the SECOND JSON with the same news but on spain language. So how it's realize?

Also i used some code, so now i parse data from JSON:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somesite.com/mainjson"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Also i have two strings localizable with english and spain languages.
So how i understand, i must to create two NSString for example:

```
NSString1 = @"http://somesite.com/mainjsonEnglish";
NSString2 = @"http://somesite.com/mainjsonSpain";
```

and after this i must to check if i have english language i must put NSString1 and the same with spain and NSString2. So any idea about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
NSString* locale = [[NSLocale systemLocale] localeIdentifier];
NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://somesite.com/mainjson.%@", locale];
```

That would give you `http://somesite.com/mainjson.en_US`

Comment: A better way would probably be to internationalize your site so that it paid attention to the Accept-Language http header and then set that to appropriate the localeIdentifier.

Comment: You could also use NSLocalizedString and Localizable.strings which is the normal localization scheme for iOS applications, but in this case it doesn't really seem appropriate.

Comment: SO i have maybe good solution but it's work!         NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"LocalizeStringUrl", nil)];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

Comment: And in string localizable i write "LocalizeStringUrl" = "and my ling there";

Comment: That's a redundant solution (you'll wind up with a language identifier in a language identifier specified file) and you'll have to update it for each added language, but if it works for you :)

Comment: With the specific solution you give here you'll also have to have an entry in your Localized.strings file for each different URL you have.  If you only have one or two that's workable, if you have more than that it will get awkward fast.

Comment: Okey i am understand. Yes its perfectly for me. I have only two language.